# Rename local GIT branch breaks Git Flow in SourceTree

Tags: git, branch, rename, git-flow, sourcetree

While using [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) I renamed the two main local branches (master and develop).
However, when I now click on the Git Flow icon to start a new feature, it tells me that the repository needs to be initialized (even though it has been already been initialized).
Additionally, the `REPOSITORY -> GIT FLOW -> INITIALIZE REPOSITORY` menu item is greyed out.

I tried putting the names of the branches back and git flow works again!

So, how do I rename the branches and keep git flow working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shut Sourcetree, and edit the file .git/config (within the repository) updating the [gitflow "branch"] section. The .git directory is sometimes hidden within file explorer.

The default will look something like this:

```
[gitflow "branch"]
master = master
develop = develop
```

And you should change it to match your new branch names, i.e.:

```
[gitflow "branch"]
master = yourNewMasterBranchName
develop = yourNewDevelopBranchName
```

Then restart SourceTree